# std::forward through an example

Tags: c++

I would like to go over an example using std::forward because sometimes I can make it work and some other times I can’t.
This is the code

```
void f(int&& int1, int&& int2){
    std::cout << "f called!\n";
}

template <class T>
void wrapper(T&& int1, T&& int2){
    f(std::forward<T>(int1), std::forward<T>(int2));
}


int main(){
    int int1 = 20;
    int int2 = 30;
    int &int3 = int1;
    wrapper(int1, int2);
}
```

1. I am passing int 1 and int 2. These are lvalues. They are silently converted to &int1, &int2. These are converted using &&. But reference collapsing keeps them just &int1, &int2.
2. f takes && parameters
3. If I pass simply int1 and int2 as they are I am passing &int1, &int2. This does not work.
4. So I pass std::forward(int1) std::forward(int2).It should be the same as  using static_cast<T&&>. Because of this, thanks to referencing collapsing I can pass to every function f (theoretically even one that accepts only l-value references).
5. My code does not compile and my logical reasoning has probably some contradictions.

```
candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int' to 'int &&' for 1st argument
void f(int&& int1, int&& int2){
```

How on earth did I get a simple int after using all these ampersands?

Additional question: My compiler asks me to use wrapper<int &> instead of only wrapper(some parameters). Can I just leave it like in my code, or I need to manually put `wrapper<int &>` (this is what my compiler is asking me to add). Why do I need <int &> int this case?

Comment: `static_cast<T&&>` with `T` = `int&` is similar to `static_cast<int&>`...

Comment: `wrapper(std::move(int1), std::move(int2));` would fix compilation.

Comment: ignoring the call to `f`, `template <class T> void wrapper(T&&, T&&);` is *"problematic"*, as both parameters should be deduced as same type,`template <class T1, class T2> void wrapper(T1&&, T2&&);` would avoid this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole problem stems from the forwarding references using same symbols as rvalue ones, but not being the same.

Take the following code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void f(T&& t)
{
//whatever
}
```

In this case `T&&` is a **forwarding reference**. It is neither T&& in the sense of rvalue-reference (reference to temporary), nor is it T&. Compiler deduces that at compile time. Notice though, it does not have type specified either, it's a template paremeter. Only in case of those parameters the forwarding reference semantics applies (another way of writing it down is a `auto&&` in lambdas, but the deduction works the same way).
Thus when you call `int x= 3; f(x);` you're effectively calling `f(int&)`. Calling `f(3)` calls effectively `f(int&&)` though.

```cpp
void g(int&& arg)
```

`arg` is and rvalue reference to int. Because the type is specified, it's not a template argument! It's always an rvalue reference.

Thus, for your case

```cpp
void f(int&& int1, int&& int2){
    std::cout << "f called!\n";
}

template <class T>
void wrapper(T&& int1, T&& int2){
    f(std::forward<T>(int1), std::forward<T>(int2));
}


int main(){
    int int1 = 20; 
    int int2 = 30;
    int &int3 = int1;
    wrapper(int1, int2); //call wrapper(int&, int&);
    //Then f(std::forward<T>(int1), std::forward<T>(int2));-> f(int&, int&), because they are lvalues! Thus, not found, compilation error!
}
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/xjTnjcqj8

Comment: yeah thanks, got it know. So I should use std::forward only when working between two templates. I mean when I have one wrapper which is a template, and another thing (like function or class which is another template) so I can use  succesfully type deduction?

Comment: see my edit, I added demo on Godbolt. Generally: you need to have function template that forwards to various overloads. Feel free to ask for more details if you need them.

Comment: yeah thanks a lot, I have seen it, and I understand all the std::forward business :)

Answer (score 4):

`forward` is used to convert the parameter back to the "valueness" it had when passed to the function.  We can see how this works using this example

```
void foo(int&) { std::cout << "foo(int&)\n"; }
void foo(int&&) { std::cout << "foo(int&&)\n"; }

template <typename T> void wrapper(T&& var) { foo(std::forward<T>(var)); }

int main()
{
    int bar = 42;
    wrapper(bar);
    wrapper(42);
}
```

which outputs

```
foo(int&)
foo(int&&)
```

So, when you pass wrapper an lvalue, `forward` will forward that along, and the lvalue accepting overload of `foo` is called.  When you pass an rvalue to wrapper, `forward` will convert `var` back into an rvalue<sup>1</sup> and the rvalue overload of `foo` is called.

Since your `f` function only accepts rvalues, that means your wrapper function will also only work for rvalues.  You are basically just trying to do `f(int1, int2)` in `main`, and that wont work.

The reason you get the error message `no known conversion from 'int' to 'int &&'` is that it is trying to tell you that there is no conversion from an lvalue `int` into a reference to an rvalue `int`.

<sup>1: This is needed because as a named variable, it is an lvalue, even if it is a reference to an rvalue.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I'll start off with something mentioned in the comments, and that is that having only one template parameter here relates the two parameters and interferes with the usual deduction process. Normally when forwarding, you deduce a type for each forwarded parameter independently. In this case, it will still work, but *only* because the call site passes two things with the same type and the same value category (lvalue, rvalue, etc.).

Here's what a typical wrapper would look like, truly forwarding the arguments independently:

```
template <class T, class T2>
void wrapper(T&& int1, T2&& int2){
    f(std::forward<T>(int1), std::forward<T2>(int2));
}
```

With that out of the way, I'll move on to the intuitive reason your code doesn't compile. If forwarding is done correctly, the wrapper function's existence won't change anything. By the above reasoning, your wrapper function meets this criteria for this particular call. Let's see what happens when it's gone:

```
 void f(int&& int1, int&& int2){
    std::cout << "f called!\n";
}

int main(){
    int int1 = 20;
    int int2 = 30;
    int &int3 = int1;
    f(int1, int2);
}
```

You might be able to spot the error more clearly now. `f` takes rvalues, but it's being given lvalues. The wrapper preserves the value category of its arguments, so they're still lvalues when handed to `f`. To fix this with the wrapper, it's the same as without—pass rvalues:

```
int main(){
    f(20, 30);
    // Alternatively: f(std::move(int1), std::move(int2));
}
```

Now, reviewing the points made:

> I am passing int 1 and int 2. These are lvalues. They are silently converted to &int1, &int2. These are converted using &&. But reference collapsing keeps them just &int1, &int2.

Don't think about the variables themselves here, but the types. Because you pass in two lvalue `int`s, `T` is deduced to be `int&`. Following that, the actual parameter types, `T&&`, are then `int&` as well because of reference collapsing. Thus, you have a function stamped out with two `int&` parameters. In the `forward` calls, `T` is `int&`, so its reference-collapsed return type is again `int&`. Thus, the call expressions have the type `int` and are lvalues (specifically because the return type is `int&`—the language calls that out as an explicit rule).

As a side note, `&int1` isn't clear to me because its C++ meaning is taking the address of `int1`, an entirely irrelevant meaning here. I think what you're trying to say is that it's an lvalue or that a parameter's type is an lvalue reference.

> If I pass simply int1 and int2 as they are I am passing &int1, &int2. This does not work.

This is true for the the reasons discussed earlier. The parameters are themselves lvalues, so a function taking rvalues won't accept them.

> So I pass std::forward(int1) std::forward(int2).It should be the same as using static_cast<T&&>. Because of this, thanks to referencing collapsing I can pass to every function f (theoretically even one that accepts only l-value references).

Yes, this is the point of forwarding. It lets you preserve the value category of the arguments given to the wrapper, so the same template can be used to pass along arguments to a function regardless of which value categories it accepts. It's up to the caller of the wrapper to provide the correct value category in the first place and then the wrapper simply promises not to mess with it.

> How on earth did I get a simple int after using all these ampersands?

This is just how the type is displayed in the error message. Although the parameter is an `int&`, the expression has the type `int`. Remember that an expression has both a type and a value category and that they're separate properties. For example, you can have an rvalue reference parameter `int&& x` and the expression `x` will still be an `int` and an lvalue.

Comment: thanks clear explanation ;). I don’t know why I wrote &int this i my bad :(